# How to get documentElement of an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html

When I run this code it does't work

```
goruncode(){
    editor = ace.edit('editor');
    var editorvaluet=editor.getValue();
    frames['screen'].document.documentElement.innerHTML = editorvaluet;" 
}
```

and in **html**

```
I have a <iframe id="screen"></iframe>
```

so when i click the update it does't update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
document.getElementById("screen").contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML
```